# Animated Text with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create an animated text with html5. Here is how it goes. 
For example i have a word telephone. I would like each alphabet to appear with a specific colour animation. However after visiting so much tutorials i cant seems to find any of them. I only found text-shadow, for instance, 
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html

It would be nice if anyone has any tutorial on such animation.

Comment: This is the wrong sort of question for this site. Go out on the web, find what you think you need, and if you find a **specific** problem when implementing your solution, then come back here.

Comment: the thing is i have been searching for the last 2 hours and i still didnt find any suitable tutorial. All are just text-shadow and some modification of text-shadow thats all.

Comment: here is a nice resource for keyframes animations: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a example using CSS3 @keyframes

```
   .letterA{
      animation:letterA 0.5s infinite;
      -webkit-animation:letterA 0.5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
   }

    @keyframes letterA{
       from {color:red;}
       to {color:blue;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes LetterA /* Safari and Chrome */{
       from {color:red;}
       to {color:blue;}
    }
```

## [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YnhwU/1)

read up on css Animations for More Browser Compatibility Versions

I still also agree that there may have been lack of research here, here is some links to google to help you out

## [Link 1](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=CSS3%20Animations&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=abd5fa99c5f6637f&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.d2k&biw=1344&bih=740)

## [Link 2](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&suggest=p&pq=css3%20animations&cp=9&gs_id=4v&xhr=t&q=css3%20@keyframes&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=CSS3%20@key&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.d2k&fp=abd5fa99c5f6637f&ion=1&biw=1344&bih=740)

## [Link 3](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&suggest=p&pq=css3%20@keyframes&cp=7&gs_id=5o&xhr=t&q=css3%20transition&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=css3%20tr&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.d2k&fp=abd5fa99c5f6637f&ion=1&biw=1344&bih=740)